# Laggy UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ipad

At the moment I'm working on an iPad explore game which has a hexagon tile map.

I've created a UIScrollView that contains a background view (the game map) and buttons in the form of hexagons (for interaction). I add every UIButton to the view via addSubview.

But... when I add more than 100 buttons the view gets laggy (no surprise here). But what should I do to solve this?

Example:

[scroll view http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/5527/screenshot2011090110353.png](http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/5527/screenshot2011090110353.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding UIButtons isn't the way to go here. You should probably draw the "buttons" in a custom -drawRect: method and use -touchesEnded:withEvent: to decide what the user wanted to do.

Comment: jep, thats the way I went :) Using `CATiledLayer` you can make it render nicely